# Dark Blue styling

Tags: language-agnostic

This is not a programming question, so I apologize if it doesn't really fit in this website.

I want to create a 3 column website where the dominating background color is dark blue, and the secondary side column is more noticeable than the tertiary column, and where the primary content area is white.

I'm thinking about this and I can't think of any ways or color choices to make it look good.

Any sources of inspiration or just color suggestions or overall style suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Before this gets smacked down:

Use http://colorschemedesigner.com/

It will give you an example of what the website will look like in the color scheme and it will also generate the template for you which is nice.

Comment: http://colorschemedesigner.com/#40520w0w0w0w0 -- I'll even set you up with dark blue. :)

Answer (score 1):

[This site](http://kuler.adobe.com/) is useful for helping with colour selections.

Answer (score 1):

Don't miss out on http://www.templatemonster.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I have found http://www.colourlovers.com/ to be about the best with coming up with color schemes.